# How to run abaqus python script in IDE editor PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, editor, abaqus

I am new to Abaqus scripting and to Python. 
I am trying to write the code on PyCharm editor but it does not recognize the Abaqus libraries. 
Is there any way to run the code on PyCharm or other editors and to visualize the data afterward?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, you will have to write your code first in any editor and use 'Run Script' option in Abaqus to run this file. You can use kernel command line interface to test lines in your code.

hope this help

Comment: Thanks, 
Do you mean the ABAQUS PDE ? (referring to the kernel command)